# php foreach saves into phpmyadin starting from zero

Tags: php

If someone can help . I would really appreciate it.
I have 12 questions with 6 radio buttons as rating for each question. (used a foreach loop) on my php questionnaire page which i created for my product. After the customer has rated the questions they press submit where it then takes them onto the next page which displays all their ratings which they selected and sends it off to phpmyadmin.

now the above says $key +1 which displays the questions starting from 1... So question #1 was rated 6, question #2 was rated 1 etc.
but when it is uploaded to phpmyadmin table it starts the question number from 0!

How can I change the above code so that it saves the questions starting from 1 into my desired table. I have tried $key + 1 in mysqlquery but doesnt seem to work .

thanks

Comment: This is not relevant for your question, but i suggest you to begin drop the mysql_* code and begin use mysqli or pdo system. Mysql_* will be deprecated shortly.

Comment: Nothing is "saved into phpmyadmin". phpmyadmin is a frontend for mysql databases. I'm not sharing this just to nitpick, but to suggest that there is a lot that you don't know besides your topics particular problem, and it might benefit you to slow down and learn thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
// If your INSERT query should be in side loop
foreach ($_POST['question'] as $key => $value) { 

$k = $key + 1;
echo 'Question #' . $k . ' You rated it ' . $value ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_responsequestions (RID,QuesID,OptionID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$k','$value')"); 

}


//If INSERT query is to be outside loop:

$key = $key + 1;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_responsequestions (RID,QuesID,OptionID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$key','$value')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic math?

```
INSERT .... VALUES (...., $key + 1, ....)
```

Comment: it doesn't work... I've already tried it. like i said in my question :( question number is still saved starting from 0 and not 1